# Trying to index data into Amazon elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, command-line, alexa-skills-kit

I am going through the following tutorial on Amazon's website to learn about how to use elastic search in my application: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-upload-data.html

When I run the command:

```
     curl -XPOST MY_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT/_bulk --data-binary 
     @bulk_movies.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I am getting the following message:

```
curl: (3) Port number ended with 'a'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: this command should be executed in a single line, hope you didn't miss that

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did execute in a single line

Comment: I think you would have copy pasted it from site or some editor... please make sure, you write single quote in `curl: (3) Port number ended with 'a'` yourself, sometime some editor changed single quote `'` .

Comment: Thanks for the followup. So I tried writing out the command myself, and I got the same message

Comment: can you tell me ur `MY_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT ` ?

Comment: Wow you just pointed out the problem to me I was stupidly copying the domain ARN instead of the endpoint I tried now it just worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP was facing the issue as he wasn't passing the proper endpoint, once he passed the proper endpoint he issue was resolved.

So to avoid these kinds of issue, Please don't copy everything from the tutorial and pass the actual values.

One issue which happens very frequently, although which wasn't the case here is quotes changes when copying from different sources like editors sublime etc or from slack etc if it's not in the code block of slack.